normalize a JSON array with jolt
I would like to "normalize" a JSON array of items with the help of jolt.
The source json would be like (number and content of attributes may vary)
[
  {
    "itemNo": 1012113,
    "item_original_no": "item1",
    "productNo": "prod1",
    "adjusting_buckles": "adjusting_buckles_shoulders | adjusting_buckles_hips | adjusting_buckles_legs",
    "anchor_point_type": null,
    "anti_twist": null,
    "attachment_points": "attachment_points_sternal_aluminium | attachment_points_dorsal_aluminium | attachment_points_side_aluminium | attachment_points_climbing_protection_aluminium",
    "attachment_points_bottom": null,
    "attachment_points_top": null,
    "backstop": null,
    "battery_range": null
  },
  {
    "itemNo": 1012108,
    "item_original_no": "item2",
    "productNo": "prod2",
    "adjusting_buckles": "adjusting_buckles_shoulders | adjusting_buckles_hips | adjusting_buckles_legs",
    "anchor_point_type": null,
    "anti_twist": null,
    "attachment_points": "attachment_points_sternal_aluminium | attachment_points_dorsal_aluminium | attachment_points_side_aluminium | attachment_points_climbing_protection_aluminium",
    "attachment_points_bottom": null,
    "attachment_points_top": null,
    "backstop": null,
    "battery_range": null
  }
]

in my expected json the itemNo should serve as an id.Each key should be the value of key "attribute" and each value should be the value of key "value".
[ 
    {"id":1012113,"attribute":"item_original_no","value":"item1"},
    {"id":1012113,"attribute":"productNo","value":"product1"},
    {"id":1012113,"attribute":"adjusting_buckles","value":"adjusting_buckles_shoulders | adjusting_buckles_hips | adjusting_buckles_legs"},
    {"id":1012113,"attribute":"anchor_point_type","value":null},
    {"id":1012113,"attribute":"anti_twist","value":null},
    {"id":1012113,"attribute":"attachment_points","value":"attachment_points_sternal_aluminium | attachment_points_dorsal_aluminium | attachment_points_side_aluminium |  attachment_points_climbing_protection_aluminium"},
    {"id":1012113,"attribute":"attachment_points_bottom","value":null},
    {"id":1012113,"attribute":"attachment_points_top","value":null},
    {"id":1012113,"attribute":"backstop","value":null},
    {"id":1012113,"attribute":"battery_range","value":null},
    {"id":1012108,"attribute":"item_original_no","value":"item2"},
    {"id":1012108,"attribute":"productNo","value":"product2"},
    {"id":1012108,"attribute":"adjusting_buckles","value":"adjusting_buckles_shoulders | adjusting_buckles_hips | adjusting_buckles_legs"},
    {"id":1012108,"attribute":"anchor_point_type","value":null},
    {"id":1012108,"attribute":"anti_twist","value":null},
    {"id":1012108,"attribute":"attachment_points","value":"attachment_points_sternal_aluminium | attachment_points_dorsal_aluminium | attachment_points_side_aluminiumattachment_points_climbing_protection_aluminium"},
    {"id":1012108,"attribute":"attachment_points_bottom","value":null},
    {"id":1012108,"attribute":"attachment_points_top","value":null},
    {"id":1012108,"attribute":"backstop","value":null},
    {"id":1012108,"attribute":"battery_range","value":null}
]

Frankly spoken my approach so far is very poor, when it commes to attributes and values.
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "itemNo": "result.[&1].id",
        "*": "result.[&1].value",
        "$": "result.[&1].attribute"
      }
    }
  }
]

Therefory any hint and help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

You can go one more level deeper to match the pairs while grouping the values by itemNo values and their respective keys for each such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@1,itemNo": "@2,itemNo.&.id",
          "$": "@2,itemNo.&.attribute",
          "@": "@2,itemNo.&.value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]


This is awesome..Thank you Barbaros
